# Change wl driver to b43?

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, aircrack-ng, b43

i managed to install Xubuntu 16.04 on a inspiron 1012. After almost 2 weeks of struggle with the black screen problem i finally got to get it going. My PCI ID is 14e4:4315 
Everything is fine, everything works, buuut:
When i try to enable monitor mode i get

Error for wireless request "Set Mode" 8B06

I´ve read in other post that this is cause by the "wl" "b43" driver problem. 
Im pretty new to Linux, so im just looking to get the driver change done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change to the b43 driver, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot.